# Troubleshooting a flow without an error message

Tags: visual-workflow, debug-logs

**The Problem:** I have a flow which is supposed to be triggered automatically by a Process Builder flow. I am running the flow, but the functionality is not working as expected. Earlier, I was getting flow error messages emailed to me, but I've solved those errors, and now the flow is running, not working as expected, but I'm not getting any error messages.

**The ask:** Can somebody help me troubleshoot my flow even though I'm not getting any error messages? You don't have to actually help me solve my flow, I just need to know how I can begin to figure out why its not working. I have run a debug log which I am attaching here, along with a screenshot of my flow. Unfortunately, I can't find any useful information inside the debug log. Any thoughts/comments/suggestions on how to troubleshoot this would be amazing.

**Order of expected automation:** When Project__c.Phase__c = "Completed", a process builder flow triggers, which in turn triggers the flow and passes it the value of Project__c.Id.

**Heads up:** There is a lot of existing code-based automation in this system which makes up the bulk of the debug log. That automation does not relate in any way to my flow, which is called, "Create Project Performance Reviews". If you want more details about what the flow is accomplishing, can tell you, but I don't think its very relevant -- I just need help with how I should be going about troubleshooting this.

Thanks in advance!

**Link to Debug Log:** https://pastebin.com/eYe4bG8h

**Screenshot of Flow:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7zMU.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line of the log includes a header that shows what your debug levels are:

```
42.0 APEX_CODE,FINEST;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WAVE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
```

These levels seem are probably not the most useful for debugging Flows. A first step you could take would be to lower the Apex Code log level (since it consumes a huge amount of your log with information we probably don't need right now) and increase the level for Workflow so that more relevant information about the execution of your Process Builder/Flow sequence is included. (Right now, almost everything useful to you is elided).

That said, I don't find debug logs for Flow especially useful or readable, but at least the information will be there.

Looking at the structure of your Flow, I would suggest that the first place to look debugging-wise is that Decision element. Since you're not receiving any errors and don't have any fault paths in place, I would suggest that the Decision is the first place to look as a culprit for why nothing happens. I'm guessing it's inaccurately evaluating to false and causing `CreatePPR` not to execute.

Comment: you were correct! Thank you very much. I didn't realise that unless all possible outcomes for a decision node lead back into the loop somehow, it won't continue to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

@David Reed's response was right on the money.

**New learning:** All outcomes from a decision node must lead back into the loop if you want it to continue iterating regardless of the outcome.

**My tip:** In the end, David's answer was correct, but I solved my issue through other means... I used the flow "Send Email" resource to help me debug. Set these up in important places in your flow to check where the flow is breaking.